# How do I manage multiple audio files in a JavaScript project?

Tags: javascript

When I click on the first button, the winter audio is loaded but when I click on summer, both work together. How can I make winter audio stop when I click on other buttons? I am working on a relaxing-music web app. I may end up having about 20 or 30 music files. How can I make one file stop when I click play on the other?

```
document.getElementById('winter').onclick =  function changeBackground() {
document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url('winter.jpg')"
        var audio = new Audio('winter.mp3');
        audio.play();
}
document.getElementById('summer').onclick =  function changeBackground() {
    document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url('summer.jpg')"
    var audio = new Audio('summer.mp3');
    audio.play();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your implementation is done pooly, because you're creating a `new Audio()` on a `changeBackground` method. So this will create a new `audio` every time the `click` event is fired.

But to answer your question, To stop an `audio` you must use `pause()` method which is defined in the Audio API.

Here's an example:

```js
// First create the audios
var audioElements = document.querySelectorAll(".audio");
var audioObj = {};

// Create audios for each element
audioElements.forEach((el, i)=>
{
  audioObj[el.getAttribute("data-name")] = new Audio((el.getAttribute("data-name") + ".mp3"));
});

// Methods to operate those audios
function playAudio(el)
{
  var audioName = el.getAttribute("data-name");
  // Create audios for each element
  Object.keys(audioObj).forEach((keyName, i)=>
  {
    if(audioName != keyName)
    {
      audioObj[keyName].pause();
      return;
    }

    audioObj[audioName].play();
    console.log(audioName);
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = audioName.concat(".png");
  });
}

function changeBackground(imageSource)
{
  document.body.style.backgroundImage = `url(${imageSource})`;
}
```

```html
<button data-name="winter" class="audio winter" onclick="return playAudio(this)">Play Winter</button>
<button data-name="summer" class="audio summer" onclick="return playAudio(this)">Play Summer</button>
<button data-name="spring" class="audio spring" onclick="return playAudio(this)">Play Spring</button>
```

So in your case, you could `pause()` all other videos when another is clicked. I have done this only to control two audios.

Comment: Thanks, what if i have more than that? Maybe 20 files or something. Is there any other way I can do that than repeating the lines in every function?

Comment: I only worked with what you gave me. Let me change the code and make it work with any number of audios.